# Integrating Fancy Box CSS in Grocery Crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, fancybox, grocery-crud

I am working on Integrating fancy box .

Following this link on [How do add fancy box in grocery crud](http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/355-answered-how-to-add-fancybox-in-grocery-crud/)

Although everything is working well, except the fancy box css  does not seems to be linked.
By default, the list_template.php(assets\grocery_crud\themes\flexigrid\views) file has fancybox css and js linked.

This is the controller code

```
 function customers_management()
{
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
                    $crud->set_js('assets/grocery_crud/js/jquery-1.8.2.js');
                    $crud->set_js('assets/grocery_crud/js/custom.js');
        $crud->set_table('customers');
        $crud->callback_column('test',array($this,'_callback_test_function'));
        $crud->display_as('salesRepEmployeeNumber','from Employeer')
             ->display_as('customerName','Name');

        $crud->set_subject('Customer');
        $crud->set_relation('salesRepEmployeeNumber','employees','lastName');

        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->_example_output($output);
}
```

The callback_function

```
function _callback_test_function($value, $row)
{
     $attributes = array(

        'width'      => '500',
        'height'     => '500',
        'scrollbars' => 'no',
        'status'     => 'yes',
        'resizable'  => 'yes',
        'screenx'    => '0',
        'screeny'    => '0',
        'class'      => 'various fancybox.ajax'

    );

    return anchor_popup('examples/test_content/'.$row->customerNumber,'Click Here', $attributes);

}
```

The custom js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".various").fancybox();
```

});

theme - flexigrid and 
grocery crud v 1.3.3

Please guide how to solve this problem.Below is the output of the above code[image]

Comment: don't see how come the css file is included in the controller

Comment: @JFK there's no css files included in the controller, which line are you talking about ?

Comment: could you solve this?